# Jsoup want to get Values where class names are same for all elements

Tags: jsoup

This is my HTML. From this i want to get two details

Publisher: Springer-Verlag,
Price: $7,284

Problem is all outer and inner class names are same. Please suggest how to get above two values from below HTML using jsoup.

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="fullname">ANALYTICAL AND BIOANALYTICAL CHEMISTRY (2011)</div>
    <div class="catbox">
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">Eigenfactor Category:</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -5px;">ANALYTIC CHEMISTRY</div>
        </div>
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">ISI Category:</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -49px;">CO EA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">Group:</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -80px;">Sci</div>
        </div>
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">Total Articles (5yrs):</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -12px;">3,544</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="catbox" style="margin-left: 20px">
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">Publisher:</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -55px;">Springer-Verlag</div>
        </div>
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">First Published:</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -35px;">2001</div>
        </div>
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1"><a href="http://journalprices.com/" title="Prices provided by JournalPrices.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px">Price:</a></div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -80px;">$7,284</div>
        </div>
        <div class="catcontents">
            <div class="contents_ct1">Cost Effectiveness:</div>
            <div class="contents_ct2" style="margin-left: -18px;">1.0302</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tgraph">
        <div class="plotB">
            <iframe src="plot1.php?issn=1618-2642" width="370px" height="220px" frameborder=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="plotB" style="margin-left: 10px">
            <iframe src="plot2.php?issn=1618-2642" width="340px" height="220px" frameborder=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know the strings 'Publisher:' and 'Price:' will not change? If not you can find elements based on these strings

Answer (score 1):

**Static HTML structure**

Assuming that the layout always follows the structure of the source you provided, you can use simple CSS selector syntax to specify which element to parse.

```
Element publisher = doc.select("div.catbox:eq(2) div.catcontents div.contents_ct2").first();
Element price = doc.select("div.catbox:eq(2) div.catcontents:eq(2) div.contents_ct2").first();
System.out.println("Publisher: " + publisher.text() + "\nPrice: " + price.text());
```

would result in the print out

```
run:
Publisher: Springer-Verlag
Price: $7,284
```

---

**Dynamic HTML structure**

If the structure isn't the same all the time, the below code should produce the same result but checks the text of the elements to identify them correctly.

```
Elements content = doc.select("div.catcontents");
Element publisher = null;
Element price = null;
for (Element element : content) {
    if(element.text().startsWith("Publisher")){
        publisher = element;
    }
    if(element.text().startsWith("Price")){
        price = element;
    }
}
System.out.println(publisher.text() + "\n" + price.text());
```

Comment: If you found this as the answer, please remember in the future to mark it as answer!